# Splitting call data to 15 minute intervals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals

I am new in python and pandas and even though I researched a lot about intervals, I couldnt find any solution for my problem, I hope someone can help

Here is a sample of my DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Mel Gibson', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:22:38', 301 ],
          ['Jim Carrey', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:27:39', 1041 ],
          ['Mel Gibson', 'German','2021-9-24 13:33:22',12]],
    columns=['specialist', 'Language', 'Interval Start', 'status_duration']
)
df['Interval Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Interval Start'])
```

What I want to do is transform status duration to 15 minute intervals and group them per specialist and per day.

My desired output should be like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Mel Gibson', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:15:00', 301 ],
          ['Jim Carrey', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:15:00', 141 ],
          ['Jim Carrey', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:30:00', 900 ],
          ['Mel Gibson', 'German','2021-9-24 13:30:00',12]],
    columns=['specialist', 'Language', 'Interval Start', 'status_duration']
)
```

So basically I need to split the seconds in status duration in 15 minute intervals until there is no remaining duration.

Edit:

My original data is like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
            data=[['Mel Gibson', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:22:38', 301 ],
                  ['Mel Gibson', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:27:40', 4678 ],
                  ['Mel Gibson', 'German','2021-9-24 13:33:22',12]],
            columns=['specialist', 'Language', 'Interval Start', 'status_duration']
        )
        df['Interval Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Interval Start'])
```

The code from Henry gives me output for only the first row, second row is skipped.

Also lets say if a call has started at 10:35:00, this interval's(10:30-10:45) can not exceed 600 seconds as there are only 10 minutes left from the start time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to make use of the quotient and remainder of `status_duration`, `explode` the result and finally add up the time by seconds:

```
ref = (df.groupby(["specialist", "Language", pd.Grouper(key="Interval Start", freq="D")], as_index=False)
         .agg(status_duration=("status_duration", lambda d: [*([900]*(d.iat[0]//900)), d.iat[0]%900]),
              Interval=("Interval Start", "first"))
         .explode("status_duration"))

ref["Interval"] = ref["Interval"].dt.floor("15min")+pd.to_timedelta(ref.groupby(ref.index).cumcount()*900, unit="sec")

print (ref)

   specialist Language status_duration            Interval
0  Jim Carrey   German             900 2021-09-23 14:15:00
0  Jim Carrey   German             141 2021-09-23 14:30:00
1  Mel Gibson   German             301 2021-09-23 14:15:00
2  Mel Gibson   German              12 2021-09-24 13:30:00
```

Comment: you are God, Henry. I would like to thank you a lot for saving me 10 days of work. If we meet one day I would like offer you a bottle of whiskey :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Comment: by the way now i have seen that, if a specialist has more than one call in the same day, code takes only the first entry, do you need more details on that?

Comment: The above was according to what you said `group them per specialist and per day`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I edited the first post to show you where it does stops working. I don't know if I missed something but it did not group everything as it skipped second row.

Comment: You really shouldn't edit a correctly answered question when you realize that the problem you described (and that someone contributed a solution to) is actually different from the problem that you want to solve. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: sorry i really did not mean any offence,or i was not being ungrateful. There was a misunderstanding and I will ask a new question as you mentioned

Comment: No offense taken and I didn't want to seem rude. I was simply pointing out that it's confusing for future visitors if the answers don't fit the question anymore because it has been edited after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dt.floor()` function for the rounding:

```
df['Interval Start'] = df['Interval Start'].dt.floor("15min")
```

Result (based on your edited data):

```
   specialist Language      Interval Start  status_duration
0  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              301
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00             4678
2  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-24 13:30:00               12
```

Then I added a column containing the number of intervals that you expect:

```
df['len'] = 1 + df['status_duration']//900
```

Result:

```
0  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              301    1
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00             4678    6
2  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-24 13:30:00               12    1
```

You can then use `numpy.repeat()` to duplicate the according rows and list comprehension with `timedelta()` to build the according intervals.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'specialist': np.repeat(df['specialist'], df['len']),
                'Language': np.repeat(df['Language'], df['len']),
                'Interval Start': [el for sublist in [[x['Interval Start'] + timedelta(minutes=15*y) for y in range(0, x['len'])] for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist],
                'status_duration': [el for sublist in [([900]*(x['len']-1)+[x['status_duration']%900]) for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist]
})
```

Result:

```
   specialist Language      Interval Start  status_duration
0  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              301
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              900
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              900
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00              900
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:15:00              900
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:30:00              178
2  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-24 13:30:00               12
```

Finally, you may want to reset the index:

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
   specialist Language      Interval Start  status_duration
0  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              301
1  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              900
2  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
3  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              900
4  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00              900
5  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:15:00              900
6  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-23 15:30:00              178
7  Mel Gibson   German 2021-09-24 13:30:00               12
```

Comment: okay but now in the 14:15-14:30 interval there is a duration of 1041 seconds which is bigger than 900 seconds(15 minutes). I need to see 141 seconds in the next interval of 14:30-14:45

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your original problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368683/arranging-call-data-from-salesforce-in-15-minute-intervals

Comment: As you mentioned i posted a new question in the link above. I must take interval start to consideration as well to calculate how many seconds remaining in that interval for status duration, but i appreciate your help until so far.

Comment: I updated my answer and posted it there. Not sure if there's not a better way though...