# Arranging call data from salesforce in 15 minute intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals, explode

I am new in python and pandas and also in stackoverflow so I apologize for any mistakes I make in advance.

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:28:00','2021-9-23 14:58:00', 1800 ],
          ['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:58:01','2021-9-23 15:00:05', 124 ],
          ['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-24 10:05:00','2021-9-24 10:15:30', 630 ],
          ['Monica Lewinsky', 'German', '2021-9-24 10:05:00','2021-9-24 10:05:30', 30 ]],
    columns=['specialist', 'language', 'interval_start', 'interval_end', 'status_duration']
)
df['interval_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['interval_start'])
df['interval_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['interval_end'])
```

output is

```
specialist  language    interval_start  interval_end    status_duration
0   Donald Trump    German  2021-09-23 14:28:00 2021-09-23 14:58:00 1800
1   Donald Trump    German  2021-09-23 14:58:01 2021-09-23 15:00:05 125
2   Donald Trump    German  2021-09-24 10:05:00 2021-09-24 10:15:30 630
3   Monica Lewinsky German  2021-09-24 10:05:00 2021-09-24 10:15:30 630
```

and my desired outcome is to have something like in below

```
specialist  language    interval    status_duration
0   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-23 14:15:00  120
1   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-23 14:30:00  900
2   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-23 14:45:00  899
3   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-23 15:00:00  5
4   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-24 10:00:00  600
5   Donald Trump    German  2021-9-24 10:15:00  30
6   Monica Lewinsky German  2021-9-24 10:15:00  30
```

I have this code from another topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362373/splitting-call-data-to-15-minute-intervals-in-pandas)

```
ref = (df.groupby(["specialist", "Language", pd.Grouper(key="Interval Start", freq="D")], as_index=False)
         .agg(status_duration=("status_duration", lambda d: [*([900]*(d.iat[0]//900)), d.iat[0]%900]),
              Interval=("Interval Start", "first"))
         .explode("status_duration"))

ref["Interval"] = ref["Interval"].dt.floor("15min")+pd.to_timedelta(ref.groupby(ref.index).cumcount()*900, unit="sec")
```

But it does not take "interval_start" into consideration, I need to check first if the status_duration will remain on same 15 mins interval or not. Hope somebody can help as it is a very advanced problem for me and i am working on it for more than 10 days.

Comment: Why the code is hardcoded with 900 ?   How can we know when we write codes to know we need to hardcode 900 ?

Comment: because in every interval there are 900 seconds(15 minutes) and status duration can not exceed this amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning a bit more, I came up with another (better) solution using `groupby()` and `explode()`. I add this as a second answer since my first one, while maybe a bit complicated, still works and I am also referencing a part of it in this answer.

---

I first added a few new columns to split up the `status_duration` into the first slice and the rest and replaced the original value of `status_duration` with an according 2-element list:

```
df['first'] = ((df['interval_start']+ pd.Timedelta('1sec')).dt.ceil('15min') - df['interval_start']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
df['rest'] = df['status_duration'] - df['first']
df['status_duration'] = df[['first','rest']].values.tolist()
df['status_duration'] = df['status_duration'].apply(lambda x: x if x[1] > 0 else [sum(x),0])
```

This gives you the following prepared dataframe:

```
        specialist language      interval_start  ... status_duration first  rest
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:28:00  ...     [120, 1680]   120  1680
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:58:01  ...        [119, 5]   119     5
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:05:00  ...       [600, 30]   600    30
3  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:05:00  ...         [30, 0]   600  -570
```

On this, you can now perform a `groupby()` and `explode()` similar to the code in your question. Afterwards you round the intervals and group again to merge the intervals that have multiple entries now because of the `explode()`. To clean up, I dropped the rows with duration `0` and reset the index:

```
ref = df.groupby(['specialist', 'language', pd.Grouper(key='interval_start', freq='T')], as_index=False)
        .agg(status_duration=('status_duration', lambda d: [d.iat[0][0],*([900]*(d.iat[0][1]//900)), d.iat[0][1]%900]),interval_start=('interval_start', 'first'))
        .explode('status_duration')

ref['interval_start'] = ref['interval_start'].dt.floor('15min')+pd.to_timedelta(ref.groupby(ref.index).cumcount()*900, unit='sec')

ref = ref.groupby(['specialist', 'language', 'interval_start']).sum()
ref = ref[ref.status_duration != 0].reset_index()
```

This gives you your desired output:

```
        specialist language      interval_start  status_duration
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              120
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              899
3     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00                5
4     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00              600
5     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:15:00               30
6  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00               30
```

---

Note: The problem I described in the other answer, that the final grouping step could result in a `status_duration` > 900 should not be possible with real data, since a specialist shouldn't be able to start a second interval before the first one ends. So this is a case you do not need to handle after all.

Comment: Thank you very much buddlemat, I can safely say this was an advanced problem but you solved like a king.

Comment: Glad to help! I learned a lot along the way... ;)

Comment: Hi there buddemat, would you like another but a bit easier challenge? I tried to alter your code for something similar but i could not break it down

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586053/calculating-chat-concurrency-from-salesforce-data-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this isn't unnecessarily convoluted, but it does get the job done. There are probably nicer, more pythonic approaches though...

I first added a few new columns to the df with the resulting number of intervals that the `status_duration` suggests, the number of minutes that fit in the first interval and the remainder of the duration:

```
df['len'] = 1 + (df['status_duration']-1)//900

df['first'] = ((df['interval_start']+timedelta(seconds=1)).dt.ceil('15min') - df['interval_start']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)

df['rest'] = df['status_duration'] - df['first']
```

Then, we add one additional interval for each row with a positive rest and a first slice < 900:

```
df['len'] = np.where((df['rest'] > 0) & (df['first'] < 900), df['len'] + 1, df['len'])
```

Now, I create the new dataframe by using `np.repeat()` to duplicate the rows so that I have the right number according to the number of intervals and list comprehensions to build the `interval_start` and `status_duration` columns using `df.iterrows()`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'specialist': np.repeat(df['specialist'], df['len']),
                 'language': np.repeat(df['language'], df['len']),
                 'interval_start': [el for sublist in [[x['interval_start'] + timedelta(minutes=15*y) for y in range(0, x['len'])] if (x['len'] > 1) else [x['interval_start']] for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist],
                 'status_duration': [el for sublist in [([x['first']]+[900]*(x['len']-2)+[x['rest']%900]) if x['len'] > 1 else [x['status_duration']] for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist]
})
```

Then we round the interval start time

```
new_df['interval_start'] = new_df['interval_start'].dt.floor('15min')
```

All that's left to do now is grouping and resetting the index:

```
new_df = new_df.groupby(['specialist', 'language', 'interval_start']).sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
        specialist language      interval_start  status_duration
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              120
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              899
3     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00                5
4     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00              600
5     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:15:00               30
6  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00               30
```

---

One problem remains: The last grouping step could result in 15-minute intervals that through the grouping again get a `status_duration` > 900.

Imagine your second row of your input data had an `interval_start` that was 2 seconds earlier:

```
        specialist language      interval_start        interval_end  status_duration
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:28:00 2021-09-23 14:58:00             1800
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:57:59 2021-09-23 15:00:03              124
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:05:00 2021-09-24 10:15:30              630 
3  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:05:00 2021-09-24 10:05:30               30
```

Then you'd wind up with a `status_duration` of `901` after grouping:

```
        specialist language      interval_start  status_duration
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              120
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              901
3     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00                3
4     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00              600
5     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:15:00               30
6  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00               30
```

This is complicated by the fact that this "splilling over" can happen multiple times. One approach would be to repeat the above steps until no `new_df` rows with `status_duration` > 900 remain. This will carry over the overflow.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:28:00','2021-9-23 14:58:00', 1800 ],
          ['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-23 14:57:59','2021-9-23 15:00:03', 124 ],
          ['Donald Trump', 'German', '2021-9-24 10:05:00','2021-9-24 10:15:30', 630 ],
          ['Monica Lewinsky', 'German', '2021-9-24 10:05:00','2021-9-24 10:05:30', 30 ]],
    columns=['specialist', 'language', 'interval_start', 'interval_end', 'status_duration']
)
input_df['interval_start'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['interval_start'])
input_df['interval_end'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['interval_end'])

def build_df(df):
    while df['status_duration'].gt(900).any():
        df['len'] = 1 + (df['status_duration']-1)//900
        df['first'] = ((df['interval_start']+timedelta(seconds=1)).dt.ceil('15min') - df['interval_start']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
        df['rest'] = df['status_duration'] - df['first']
        df['len'] = np.where((df['rest'] > 0) & (df['first'] < 900), df['len'] + 1, df['len'])
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'specialist': np.repeat(df['specialist'], df['len']),
                 'language': np.repeat(df['language'], df['len']),
                 'interval_start': [el for sublist in [[x['interval_start'] + timedelta(minutes=15*y) for y in range(0, x['len'])] if (x['len'] > 1) else [x['interval_start']] for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist],
                 'status_duration': [el for sublist in [([x['first']]+[900]*(x['len']-2)+[x['rest']%900]) if x['len'] > 1 else [x['status_duration']] for i, x in df.iterrows()] for el in sublist]
        })
        new_df['interval_start'] = new_df['interval_start'].dt.floor('15min')
        new_df = new_df[new_df.status_duration != 0]
        new_df = new_df.groupby(['specialist', 'language', 'interval_start']).sum().reset_index()
        df = new_df.copy()
    return df

output_df = build_df(input_df)
```

Result:

```
        specialist language      interval_start  status_duration
0     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:15:00              120
1     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:30:00              900
2     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 14:45:00              900
3     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-23 15:00:00                4
4     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00              600
5     Donald Trump   German 2021-09-24 10:15:00               30
6  Monica Lewinsky   German 2021-09-24 10:00:00               30
```

Looking at it now, I would guess that there should probably be an easier way, but this is all I got...